# Is there a name for a list data structure where all of the elements have a pointer to the list?

Tags: data-structures

Is there a name for a list data structure where all of the elements have a pointer to the list or another common object?  The list maintains this relationship by setting the pointer when items are added, and removing them when items are removed.

The purpose of the structure is to provide a way to find the common object from an element given that you don't want to pass the common object around everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).